# Looking for tile-grid polygon layer

Tags: web-mapping, tiles, grids-graticules

I'm looking for a vector-grid that has grid-cell boundaries for every tile/zoom-level in the standard x/y/z web-map tiling scheme. Googling has done me no good...anyone know of a source?